# How do i learn syntax for Appium automation?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have just started learning Appium automation and I use online tutorials to learn the syntax of various classes.
I thought that this is an official site of appium but when i refer to syntax , it does not work.
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/tap/index.html

For example, for tap action with single click below syntax is given but i get an error when i actually use this code. It gives me an error for singleTap. This is just an example. I need source data to lean syntax and functions of each class.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='1. Photos']"));
TouchActions action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.singleTap(element);
action.perform();
```

The error message is as follows:

```
The method singleTap(WebElement) is undefined for the type TouchAction.
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The error message is   "The method  singleTap(WebElement) is undefined for the type TouchAction.//click on gallery
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Gallery']")).click();
 
WebElement photo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='1. Photos']"));
TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);
  t.singleTap(photo);
  t.perform();